# Query elasticsearch for Analyze Text

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I transfrom this Elasticsearch REST query:

```
http://x.x.x.x:9200/_analyze?analyzer=standard&text="text text text"
```

into Java API client?

I have test with:

```
client.prepareSearch("index").setQuery("_analyze?analyzer=standard&text='text text text'").execute().actionGet()
```

but it doesn't work

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
AnalyzeResponse analyzeResponse = client.admin().indices().prepareAnalyze("my_index", "text text text").setAnalyzer("standard").execute().actionGet();
```

And when in doubt, look at [this](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/blob/master/src/test/java/org/elasticsearch/indices/analyze/AnalyzeActionTests.java#L89) class from Elasticsearch own testing code.